How to install deb822 apt repositories using ansible's apt_repository module?
I have started using ansible in the past year or so to automate the setup of my development environment in WSL Ubuntu distros. However I have avoided the usage of apt_repository since in Ubuntu 20 it was trying to install repository keys to the deprecated /etc/apt/trusted.gpg, while Ubuntu 20 and Ubuntu 22 with add-apt-repository would install repository keys to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/. A number of answers here on stackoverflow encourage storing keys to etc/apt/keyring rather than /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ which they say is deprecated, but Ubuntu 20 and Ubuntu 22 will always install keys to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ while considering /etc/apt/trusted.gpg to be deprecated.
I have now been testing adding repositories to Ubuntu 24, and I see it installs keys directly inside /etc/apt/sources.list.d in the same file as the repository, for example sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php will result in a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-noble.sources file with contents:
Types: deb
URIs: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/
Suites: noble
Components: main
Signed-By:
 -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
 .
 mQINBGYo0vEBEAC0Semxy5I2b8exRUxJfTKkHR4f5uyS0dTd9vYgMI5T3gsa7ypH
 HtE+GiZC+T9m/F9h66+XJMxhuNsKRs7T2In5NSeso9H/ytlSTayUaBtCFfRp6y6b
 6ozuRBfqYJGxhjAnIzvNF/Wpp2BvfQm3OrQ7uJJrt5IvzLDC4jPxl/Xs3sTT+Hbk
 bkKKprZ3xmy2enuwBaNWR/CUtAz3hbkzL1kGbhX9m3QidFJagVVdDw3aNEwo8ush
 djWfF+BajNvpDFYJKBGQbCeagB753Baa5yIN62x+THLnLiKTMDS1e7U0ZDiV9671
 noTbtN5TeZeyfsEmeZ8X60x11JIP3yYHYZT70/DyTYX3WC9yQFyIgVOfRlGklMKI
 k3TLMmtq8w5Hz1vovwzV7PzaQnmY+uNP2ZbAP4fJ3iFAj0L+u0i1nOFgTy0Lq058
 O/FjRrQxuceDDCF+9ThspXMw3Puvz8giuBDCdEda84uC7XWMdqgz/maLfFQjAmyP
 Ixi1EMxMlHYyZajpR1cdCfrAIQlnQjHSWmyeCFgXPPfRA71aCcJ7oSrDjogW6Ahd
 HRkQRKf1FF9BFzycgSQotfR+7CKfPQh1kghufM9W/spARzA709nGZjXJzgEJLQd3
 CDB6dIIxT/0YI36h3Qgfmiiw4twO24MMEqEEPIELz2WJKeWGkdQdcekpxQARAQAB
 tB9MYXVuY2hwYWQgUFBBIGZvciBPbmTFmWVqIFN1csO9iQJOBBMBCgA4FiEEuNx+
 U5RmVu+85MHdcdrqq0rUyrYFAmYo0vECGwMFCwkIBwIGFQoJCAsCBBYCAwECHgEC
 F4AACgkQcdrqq0rUyrYOPQ/+IArA4s1J3op/w7cXek0ieFHWHFDrxPYS+78/LF/J
 LoYZw0nIU5Ovr+LzehFMIQU6esgPXwbeCVgwLwat57augAkAYWT0UzH5dE6RKAGr
 C2vsHWVfPhQn6UndfzwXc0mTLGQni25aQaZ6k60Dbm/vblejrTQrtAUWoMO3Z1cr
 NDGJ3Z9DCxtr2o9gRYUI6HwLHJtobTIeI5xsr5x+GvXiIAVCPa3ZEuRL6jMQfqfS
 C43mpuiS1kGgsnQLs2DbN7EFCfiJoNX1QzZu25zg+IS9PXbCJnheZWnH0rwUSb/N
 hZPcSefGlNlhr824OfT30v79hQnw59XbsfV270O9jPbD4kttN+OiszbU66zsuiOh
 BO46XCckQPqDkBMw56GPFuVrQgGb1thXvn67URJgPyJhwauBWKPNAJ9Ojuo+yVq/
 hdR1VNWThXQbZgaGSWrbjt6FdYtQb9VX88uu5gFDmr180HogHNUDUcqNLLdnjfFs
 4DyJlusQ5I/a7cQ7nlkNgxAmHszwO/mGLBuGljDUYkwZDW9nqP1Q5Q2jMtrhgXvR
 2SOtufvecUbB7+eoRSaOnu7CNMATG6LocFEMzhKUde1uZTfWSqnYEcdqoFJMi46y
 qaNxhiNLsQ5OBMbgSp2zCbQxRBdITMVvBR5YjCetUIGEs6T1yQ5wh5Xpoi34ShHn
 v38=
 =kFlZ
 -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

So I'm wondering (seeing the apparent lack of ansible documentation in these regards), how does ansible now in 2024 handle apt repositories in Ubuntu 24 environments?
UPDATE: Here is some more information from my current tests. Running this task in ansible on Ubuntu 24:
- name: Verify that the Ondrej PHP PPA is present
  apt_repository:
    repo: ppa:ondrej/php
    state: present

I can see that it is still using the deprecated apt-key and trying to install public keys to the deprecated /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/apt-key adv --recv-keys --no-tty --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 B8DC7E53946656EFBCE4C1DD71DAEAAB4AD4CAB6", "msg": "Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).\ngpg: key 71DAEAAB4AD4CAB6: public key \"Launchpad PPA for Ondřej Surý\" imported\ngpg: Total number processed: 1\ngpg:               imported: 1\n/usr/bin/apt-key: 391: cannot create /etc/apt/trusted.gpg: Permission denied\ncat: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.1pZUPb5Fp7/gpgoutput.log: No such file or directory", "rc": 1, "stderr": "Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).\ngpg: key 71DAEAAB4AD4CAB6: public key \"Launchpad PPA for Ondřej Surý\" imported\ngpg: Total number processed: 1\ngpg:               imported: 1\n/usr/bin/apt-key: 391: cannot create /etc/apt/trusted.gpg: Permission denied\ncat: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.1pZUPb5Fp7/gpgoutput.log: No such file or directory\n", "stderr_lines": ["Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).", "gpg: key 71DAEAAB4AD4CAB6: public key \"Launchpad PPA for Ondřej Surý\" imported", "gpg: Total number processed: 1", "gpg:               imported: 1", "/usr/bin/apt-key: 391: cannot create /etc/apt/trusted.gpg: Permission denied", "cat: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.1pZUPb5Fp7/gpgoutput.log: No such file or directory"], "stdout": "Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.1pZUPb5Fp7/gpg.1.sh --recv-keys --no-tty --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 B8DC7E53946656EFBCE4C1DD71DAEAAB4AD4CAB6\n", "stdout_lines": ["Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.1pZUPb5Fp7/gpg.1.sh --recv-keys --no-tty --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 B8DC7E53946656EFBCE4C1DD71DAEAAB4AD4CAB6"]}

So the question is: how should apt repositories be added correctly in Ubuntu distros using ansible?

The launchpad Ansible packages work fine. However, the best practice is running Ansible in Python virtual environment. These RH instructions work also in Ubuntu. Ansible doc Installing Ansible covers, quote: "the officially supported means of installing the python packages with pip." I recommend the virtual environment. It works for me in Ubuntu 24.04.

@VladimirBotka I'm not talking about how I should install Ansible. I'm talking about how Ansible handles installing apt repositories in Ubuntu 24 using apt_repository vs how the system shell would install the repository using add-apt-repository.

The difference is in the format and the default filename. The command add-apt-repository shouldn't install any keys. Post [mre] if you want to proceed.

What is exactly your issue here? Is it a security one? Mind that a public key is what its name claim, it is meant to be public. For examples, here are your public keys: https://github.com/JohnRDOrazio.keys. The fact that a public key is present in a file should not be a concern and people telling you this should belong in a keyring does not seems to understand the principle of a public/private key pair.

@VladimirBotka When you issue add-apt-repository from the terminal, of course it installs the keys for that repository: just look at the result of issuing sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php which I posted in the original question.

@β.εηοιτ.βε I'm not contesting the fact that a public key get's installed. The question is: where should it be installed. Each distro decides what the best method and location is for storing the key. And ansible hasn't always lined up with the preferred method for distros such as Ubuntu.

You are right. man add-apt-repository says: "The GPG public key of the PPA will also be downloaded and added to apt's keyring." See Where is the documentation for the new apt sources format used in 24.04?. The ansible module deb822_repository implemented the DEB822 format.

I don't understand why this question was closed, but following up on @VladimirBotka's last comment I also found https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2022/aptkey-deprecated-debianubuntu-how-fix-ansible which leads to some examples at https://gist.github.com/roib20/27fde10af195cee1c1f8ac5f68be7e9b. Note that the python3-debian package is required (in a venv use pip install python-debian).

Taking into account @vladimir-botka's comment which set me on the right track to finding a solution to adding apt repositories in Ubuntu 24.04 using Ansible, I also found @geerlingguy's blog post entitled apt_key deprecated in Debian/Ubuntu - how to fix in Ansible, with it's 2023 update that mentions Ansible's new ansible.builtin.deb822_repository. Upon attempting to use this module I found that it requires the python3-debian package:
sudo apt install python3-debian

Or better yet, using Ansible within a python virtual environment:
pip install python-debian

Here is my working example of installing Ondrej Sury's PHP PPA as closely as the system would when running sudo add-apt-respository ppa:ondrej/php:
- name: Manage PHP PPA repository (deb822_repository)
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.deb822_repository:
    state: present
    name: "ondrej-ubuntu-php-{{ansible_distribution_release}}"
    types: [deb]
    uris: [https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu]
    suites: ["{{ ansible_facts['distribution_release'] }}"]
    components: [main]
    signed_by: |
      -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
      .
      mQINBGYo0vEBEAC0Semxy5I2b8exRUxJfTKkHR4f5uyS0dTd9vYgMI5T3gsa7ypH
      HtE+GiZC+T9m/F9h66+XJMxhuNsKRs7T2In5NSeso9H/ytlSTayUaBtCFfRp6y6b
      6ozuRBfqYJGxhjAnIzvNF/Wpp2BvfQm3OrQ7uJJrt5IvzLDC4jPxl/Xs3sTT+Hbk
      bkKKprZ3xmy2enuwBaNWR/CUtAz3hbkzL1kGbhX9m3QidFJagVVdDw3aNEwo8ush
      djWfF+BajNvpDFYJKBGQbCeagB753Baa5yIN62x+THLnLiKTMDS1e7U0ZDiV9671
      noTbtN5TeZeyfsEmeZ8X60x11JIP3yYHYZT70/DyTYX3WC9yQFyIgVOfRlGklMKI
      k3TLMmtq8w5Hz1vovwzV7PzaQnmY+uNP2ZbAP4fJ3iFAj0L+u0i1nOFgTy0Lq058
      O/FjRrQxuceDDCF+9ThspXMw3Puvz8giuBDCdEda84uC7XWMdqgz/maLfFQjAmyP
      Ixi1EMxMlHYyZajpR1cdCfrAIQlnQjHSWmyeCFgXPPfRA71aCcJ7oSrDjogW6Ahd
      HRkQRKf1FF9BFzycgSQotfR+7CKfPQh1kghufM9W/spARzA709nGZjXJzgEJLQd3
      CDB6dIIxT/0YI36h3Qgfmiiw4twO24MMEqEEPIELz2WJKeWGkdQdcekpxQARAQAB
      tB9MYXVuY2hwYWQgUFBBIGZvciBPbmTFmWVqIFN1csO9iQJOBBMBCgA4FiEEuNx+
      U5RmVu+85MHdcdrqq0rUyrYFAmYo0vECGwMFCwkIBwIGFQoJCAsCBBYCAwECHgEC
      F4AACgkQcdrqq0rUyrYOPQ/+IArA4s1J3op/w7cXek0ieFHWHFDrxPYS+78/LF/J
      LoYZw0nIU5Ovr+LzehFMIQU6esgPXwbeCVgwLwat57augAkAYWT0UzH5dE6RKAGr
      C2vsHWVfPhQn6UndfzwXc0mTLGQni25aQaZ6k60Dbm/vblejrTQrtAUWoMO3Z1cr
      NDGJ3Z9DCxtr2o9gRYUI6HwLHJtobTIeI5xsr5x+GvXiIAVCPa3ZEuRL6jMQfqfS
      C43mpuiS1kGgsnQLs2DbN7EFCfiJoNX1QzZu25zg+IS9PXbCJnheZWnH0rwUSb/N
      hZPcSefGlNlhr824OfT30v79hQnw59XbsfV270O9jPbD4kttN+OiszbU66zsuiOh
      BO46XCckQPqDkBMw56GPFuVrQgGb1thXvn67URJgPyJhwauBWKPNAJ9Ojuo+yVq/
      hdR1VNWThXQbZgaGSWrbjt6FdYtQb9VX88uu5gFDmr180HogHNUDUcqNLLdnjfFs
      4DyJlusQ5I/a7cQ7nlkNgxAmHszwO/mGLBuGljDUYkwZDW9nqP1Q5Q2jMtrhgXvR
      2SOtufvecUbB7+eoRSaOnu7CNMATG6LocFEMzhKUde1uZTfWSqnYEcdqoFJMi46y
      qaNxhiNLsQ5OBMbgSp2zCbQxRBdITMVvBR5YjCetUIGEs6T1yQ5wh5Xpoi34ShHn
      v38=
      =kFlZ
      -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

This will result in a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-noble.sources file named just as it would have been by running sudo add-apt-repository.
Also, Ubuntu 24.04 in adopting the deb822 repository format no longer stores the repository public keys in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/, but stores the key for a repository directly in the repository .source file as shown in the original question.
The resulting contents of the repository .source file after running the ansible task:
Components: main
X-Repolib-Name: ondrej-ubuntu-php-noble
Signed-By:
    -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
    .
    mQINBGYo0vEBEAC0Semxy5I2b8exRUxJfTKkHR4f5uyS0dTd9vYgMI5T3gsa7ypH
    HtE+GiZC+T9m/F9h66+XJMxhuNsKRs7T2In5NSeso9H/ytlSTayUaBtCFfRp6y6b
    6ozuRBfqYJGxhjAnIzvNF/Wpp2BvfQm3OrQ7uJJrt5IvzLDC4jPxl/Xs3sTT+Hbk
    bkKKprZ3xmy2enuwBaNWR/CUtAz3hbkzL1kGbhX9m3QidFJagVVdDw3aNEwo8ush
    djWfF+BajNvpDFYJKBGQbCeagB753Baa5yIN62x+THLnLiKTMDS1e7U0ZDiV9671
    noTbtN5TeZeyfsEmeZ8X60x11JIP3yYHYZT70/DyTYX3WC9yQFyIgVOfRlGklMKI
    k3TLMmtq8w5Hz1vovwzV7PzaQnmY+uNP2ZbAP4fJ3iFAj0L+u0i1nOFgTy0Lq058
    O/FjRrQxuceDDCF+9ThspXMw3Puvz8giuBDCdEda84uC7XWMdqgz/maLfFQjAmyP
    Ixi1EMxMlHYyZajpR1cdCfrAIQlnQjHSWmyeCFgXPPfRA71aCcJ7oSrDjogW6Ahd
    HRkQRKf1FF9BFzycgSQotfR+7CKfPQh1kghufM9W/spARzA709nGZjXJzgEJLQd3
    CDB6dIIxT/0YI36h3Qgfmiiw4twO24MMEqEEPIELz2WJKeWGkdQdcekpxQARAQAB
    tB9MYXVuY2hwYWQgUFBBIGZvciBPbmTFmWVqIFN1csO9iQJOBBMBCgA4FiEEuNx+
    U5RmVu+85MHdcdrqq0rUyrYFAmYo0vECGwMFCwkIBwIGFQoJCAsCBBYCAwECHgEC
    F4AACgkQcdrqq0rUyrYOPQ/+IArA4s1J3op/w7cXek0ieFHWHFDrxPYS+78/LF/J
    LoYZw0nIU5Ovr+LzehFMIQU6esgPXwbeCVgwLwat57augAkAYWT0UzH5dE6RKAGr
    C2vsHWVfPhQn6UndfzwXc0mTLGQni25aQaZ6k60Dbm/vblejrTQrtAUWoMO3Z1cr
    NDGJ3Z9DCxtr2o9gRYUI6HwLHJtobTIeI5xsr5x+GvXiIAVCPa3ZEuRL6jMQfqfS
    C43mpuiS1kGgsnQLs2DbN7EFCfiJoNX1QzZu25zg+IS9PXbCJnheZWnH0rwUSb/N
    hZPcSefGlNlhr824OfT30v79hQnw59XbsfV270O9jPbD4kttN+OiszbU66zsuiOh
    BO46XCckQPqDkBMw56GPFuVrQgGb1thXvn67URJgPyJhwauBWKPNAJ9Ojuo+yVq/
    hdR1VNWThXQbZgaGSWrbjt6FdYtQb9VX88uu5gFDmr180HogHNUDUcqNLLdnjfFs
    4DyJlusQ5I/a7cQ7nlkNgxAmHszwO/mGLBuGljDUYkwZDW9nqP1Q5Q2jMtrhgXvR
    2SOtufvecUbB7+eoRSaOnu7CNMATG6LocFEMzhKUde1uZTfWSqnYEcdqoFJMi46y
    qaNxhiNLsQ5OBMbgSp2zCbQxRBdITMVvBR5YjCetUIGEs6T1yQ5wh5Xpoi34ShHn
    v38=
    =kFlZ
    -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Suites: noble
Types: deb
URIs: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu

This result is practically identical to the system add-apt-repository with the sole difference that the system command does not add an X-Repolib-Name: key while the ansible task does. For the rest it's identical.
The only drawback here is that you would need to know the public key in ASCII format ahead of time and include it as a string within the ansible task. The closest I can come so far to automating retrieval of the key in ASCII format as a one-liner on the command line is:
export TMPGNUPG=$(mktemp -d) && GNUPGHOME=$TMPGNUPG gpg -q --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B8DC7E53946656EFBCE4C1DD71DAEAAB4AD4CAB6 && GNUPGHOME=$TMPGNUPG gpg -ao - --export B8DC7E53946656EFBCE4C1DD71DAEAAB4AD4CAB6 && rm -R $TMPGNUPG && unset TMPGNUPG

Now, if we also want to automate the retrieval of the public key associated with a PPA without knowing it ahead of time or without having it's fingerprint, we can scrape the repository webpage to extract the key fingerprint and subsequently retrieve the public key, given that repository archive pages on the launchpad website all have a <script> element that contains a JSON object assigned to a variable LP.cache, and we can find the fingerprint within that JSON representation:
- name: Extract signing key fingerprint from Launchpad PPA page
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Download PPA page content
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        ppa_page_content: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.url', 'https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/') }}"
      
    - name: Extract JSON from the PPA page content using regex
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        ppa_json_cache: "{{ ppa_page_content | regex_search('LP\\.cache = (\\{.*\\});</script>', '\\1') }}"

    - name: Parse JSON to extract signing key fingerprint
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        signing_key_fingerprint: "{{ ppa_json_cache | from_json | json_query('context.signing_key_fingerprint') }}"
      
    - name: Display the signing key fingerprint
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "The signing key fingerprint is: {{ signing_key_fingerprint }}"

    - name: Retrieve ASCII representation of the key using the signing key fingerprint
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        signing_key_ascii: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.url', 'https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x{{ signing_key_fingerprint }}') }}"

Now we can substitute the hardcoded ASCII string in the previous Manage PHP PPA repository (deb822_repository) task with the signging_key_ascii variable, and voilà we have an automated process.
UPDATE 7 Sept. 2024:
I just found out that launchpad actually has an API, that makes retrieval of the public signing key fingerprint much easier without having to scrape the archive webpage. Here's an example that substitutes the scraping step above with a call to the API:
---
- name: Make API request to Launchpad
  uri:
    url: "https://api.launchpad.net/devel/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php"
    return_content: yes
    method: GET
    headers:
      Accept: "application/json"
  register: launchpad_response

- name: Parse JSON to extract signing key fingerprint
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    signing_key_fingerprint: "{{ launchpad_response.json.signing_key_fingerprint }}"


